# How to check if user's status is active in laravel 5.x?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authorization

I have set a bit different login logic in AuthController provided by laravel 5.2. The code is

```
 protected function authenticated(Request $request)
    {

        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'is_active' => 1])) {
            return redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
        }

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

The code works fine. But the problem when user is not active, it still get logged in as users. So how do i stop authenticating users with `is_active = 0`?

**UPDATE: User Migration**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password', 60);
    $table->tinyInteger('is_active', 0);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Can you post your user migration. The logic your using for attempt is correct so likely a problem with the type of column or something like that.

Comment: If you use [Soft Deletion][1] on your User model, Laravel will automatically do this for you. You'll just have to convert your `is_active` to a `deleted_at` column


  [1]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: @MarkDavidson here is user migration http://pastebin.com/0J0fw4Tp

Comment: @LionelShrestha I've edited your question to include the relevant code from your comment above. In the future, best to add code to the question rather than comments.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the best field type to use for these types of fields would be boolean. Eloquent takes care of casting the 0's and 1's to falses and trues. `$table->boolean('is_active')->default(false);`

Comment: While I agree with @PatrickStephan, your logic _should_ be working. Laravel docs for [Specifying Additional Conditions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users) uses your approach as well. I also inspected the `attempt` method in `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php` and following the flow, this approach seems it should work. Have you tried clearing cache then retrying? This method does call the `lastAttempted` method, perhaps there is stale data there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the correct way to do it : http://laravel.io/forum/11-04-2014-laravel-5-how-do-i-create-a-custom-auth-in-laravel-5?page=1#reply-29759

Your method won't work because the Laravel default Auth::attempt will not check the is_active condition.