# Laravel 5.3: How to authenticate only active users

Tags: laravel-5

I want to laravel 5.3 loged in users table status='Active' but status='Inactive' can't loged in.

Please help me with that. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if user's status is active in laravel 5.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905258/how-to-check-if-users-status-is-active-in-laravel-5-x)

Answer (score 1):

Go to \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php
then change credentials functions.
And see this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/allowing-only-active-users-to-login.

example function link

protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        $crendentials =  $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
        $crendentials['status']='Active';
        return $crendentials;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Add this function in Auth/LoginController.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return [
        $this->username() => $request->get($this->username()),
        'password' => $request->get('password'),
        'active' => 1
    ];
}
```

By doing this, you actually override it. This function is in the AuthenticatesUsers trait.

Another way for getting the same result is to override the validateLogin() function by adding

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() =>  [
            'required',
            Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('active', 1);
            }),
        ], 
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

to the LoginController.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 'Active'])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```